# Random distribution of objects over a plane

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a game which involves the player walking around a forest, and so I need to randomly distribute trees from the sapling tree generator all over it. The plane is huge so I can't simply place them manually.
It would also be ideal to change the seed of the tree for each tree created. I'm familiar with python so a script would be acceptable.
Thanks!

Comment: Particles are what you're looking for, I think

Comment: @GiantCowFilms how would I use this to do it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, since I don't work in the game engine much

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Okay, well I'll see if it works

Comment: @GiantCowFilms oh it seems I can't use particles in the game engine

Comment: @GiantCowFilms actually the particles worked eventually so if you put that solution as an answer I'll make it the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it is with particles. The particle system would duplicate a specific tree object and distribute it. There is a button in the modifiers tab (if a particle system is present for the object) that makes all the particles into individual oobjects. I won't provide specific step by step instructions on how to set up the particle system, but I hope that works.
However, on most cases Python script would be preferable for what you want. You'll probably to distribute multiple tree models to provide variations, and you'd need a Python script for that.

EDIT: well **now** I see the comments under the question. This is probably useless. XD

Comment: Actually it's still useful, the modifiers tab part helps @TheMinecraftMan757

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the [Asset Sketcher](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/blender/all-products/asset-sketcher-blender-addon/) commercial addon on CG Cookie Market. Perhaps you can modify it to randomize the Sapling seed value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python. Get the list of verts in the terrain then iterate through them and randomly assign each coordinate as covered or empty. Covered ones get a tree or bush object or the like. I built exactly this a while back. Let me know if you'd like an example script.